# VMware vCLI Perl "who done it" script

Tags: perl, scripting, vmware, powercli

I've been trying to do this for a while and I just can't seem to understand the vCLI SDK. I believe the MO that I want to use is 
`ServiceContent->Task Manager`, then print out the recent task. Here is my subroutine for doing it:

```
sub TaskManager {
    my $begin;
    my $mor = Vim::get_service_content()->taskManager;
    my $taskmanager_view = Vim::get_view(mo_ref => $mor);

    my $my_filterSpec = TaskFilterSpec->new();
    my $eventArray = $taskmanager_view->CreateCollectorForTasks(filter => $my_filterSpec);
    foreach (@$eventArray) {
        # my $collector_view = Vim::get_view(mo_ref => $eventArray);
        print $_->recentTask . "\n";
    }
}
```

When I run this I either get:

Not an ARRAY reference at ./TaskManager.pl line 43.

When I change this, I then get:

`subroutine &ManagedObjectReference::recentTask called at ./TaskManager.pl line 45`

Here's one of the DOCS I've been looking at

https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk400pubs/ReferenceGuide/vim.TaskManager.html

I also have some conversations happening here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/vmware/comments/4qfaql/help_with_vcli_perl_script/

---

EDIT: I changed my subroutine to the following:

```
sub TaskManager {
    my $begin;
    my $mor = Vim::get_service_content()->taskManager;
    my $taskmanager_view = Vim::get_view(mo_ref => $mor);
    my $my_filterSpec = TaskFilterSpec->new();
    my $eventArray = $taskmanager_view->CreateCollectorForTasks(filter => $my_filterSpec);
    foreach ($eventArray) {
        my $newRecentTask = $taskmanager_view->description;
        print $newRecentTask . "\n";
    }
}
```

But the problem is that the print statement is returning a hash value, not something I can use. Any ideas how to get something readable?

Comment: When you changed your `foreach (@$eventArray) {...}` loop to `foreach ($eventArray) {...}`, you changed it to iterate over a *reference* (Remember that the `$` sigil is for scalars). In fact, your new code doesn't use `$eventArray` at all (either through an explicit iterating variable or implicitly through `$_`). Subroutines in Perl (and other scripting languages like Ruby) implicitly return the last evaluated statement (which is `print` in this case, as you correctly guessed).

Comment: So is that the reason why i'm getting a hash returned when I run it?

Comment: Probably not. At least, not entirely. It is probably because `description` is an object, not a simple string ([see this](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk400pubs/ReferenceGuide/vim.TaskDescription.html)).